# difference of difference is constant question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why is the difference of the differences of squares is 2?
e.g.: 4, 9, 16, 25, 36 ... are all squares, 
the difference of two adjacent are: 5, 7, 9, 11 ... 
and the difference of that is always 2,
why is that happening?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function is $f(n)=n^2$, the difference is 
$$f(n+1)-f(n)=(n+1)^2-n^2=n^2+2n+1-n^2=2n+1:=g(n)$$

Now if you take the next difference it is 
$$g(n+1)-g(n)=2(n+1)+1-(2n+1)=2$$

This kind of thing you can find in calculus of finite differences.

We can define an operator $\Delta$, such that $\Delta f(n)=f(n+1)-f(n)$

and applying "m" times 
$$ \Delta^m f(n).$$
If we have $f(n)$ polynomial of degree "m", we can show in general
$$\Delta^m f(n)=C $$
where $C$ is a constant.

**Edit:** We can show that $C= m! a_m$ where $f(x)=a_mx^m+\ldots+a_0x^0$

In your case $f(x)=x^2$ then $\Delta^2 x^2=C=2!.1=2.$

Comment: That operator is the discrete derivative, right?

Comment: Yes! you are right : ) (and they have very similar properties  and analogies with the "continuous" derivative)
1-Linear 2 reduce the degree of polynomial 3- something like taylor series (the newton interpolation formula) 4-Fundamental theorem of calculus (the telescopic sum). And so on

Answer (score 1):

Series of squares is $(x-1)^2, x^2, (x+1)^2$.

Series of difference of squares is $x^2-(x-1)^2=2x-1, (x+1)^2-x^2=2x+1$.

and series of difference of difference is $2x+1-(2x-1)=2$.